# Angular display Object in array via *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have the following set of data coming from a JSON file which I am trying to display via "*ngFor" in my template. I can display most of it except the "people" Objects. There can be any amount of "people" Objects. This example data set only has 2 in it.

```
  [{
  "caseNumber": "01/01/2020",
  "caseData": {
    "caseType": "Criminal",
    "caseCompName": "",
    "caseCompNumber": "12121212",
    "caseDate": "01/02/2019",
    "caseTime": "12:00",
    "caseStatus": "Open"
  },
  "people": [{
    "name": "Paul",
    "lastName": "Von Zeuner",
    "middleName": "Waldemar",
    "dob": "1981-09-29",
    "countryBirth": "South Africa"
  },{
    "name": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "middleName": "Steve",
    "dob": "1981-09-29",
    "countryBirth": "South Africa"
  }]
 }]
```

I attempted something like this but it only displays the first person. Im not sure if the Array itself is incorrectly structured or if the *ngFor is the problem

```
    <div *ngFor='let item of caseData; let i=index'>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            Name: {{item.people[i].name}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            Last Name: {{item.people[i].lastName}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            Middel Name: {{item.people[i].middleName}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            Country of Birth: {{item.people[i].countryBirth}}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please assist me

Comment: i is the index of the loop iterating over the items of your **outer** array. You need an inner loop  iterating over each item's people array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 2 ngFor in you'r html.

try this code :

```
<div *ngFor='let item of caseData; let i=index'>
    <div *ngFor="let person of item.people" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            Name: {{person.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            Last Name: {{person.lastName}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            Middel Name: {{person.middleName}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            Country of Birth: {{person.countryBirth}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijmwlw?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've created a working sample on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vq1kk3) take a look.

In the **component.ts**

```
 data =[{
  "caseNumber": "01/01/2020",
  "caseData": {
    "caseType": "Criminal",
    "caseCompName": "",
    "caseCompNumber": "12121212",
    "caseDate": "01/02/2019",
    "caseTime": "12:00",
    "caseStatus": "Open"
  },
  "people": [{
    "name": "Paul",
    "lastName": "Von Zeuner",
    "middleName": "Waldemar",
    "dob": "1981-09-29",
    "countryBirth": "South Africa"
  },{
    "name": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "middleName": "Steve",
    "dob": "1981-09-29",
    "countryBirth": "South Africa"
  }]
 }];
```

In the **component.html**

```
<div *ngFor='let item of data; let i=index'>
    <div *ngFor="let person of item.people">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                Name: {{person.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                Last Name: {{person.lastName}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                Middel Name: {{person.middleName}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                Country of Birth: {{person.countryBirth}}
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div *ngFor='let item of people; let i=index'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        Name: {{item.name}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        Last Name: {{item.lastName}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        Middel Name: {{item.middleName}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        Country of Birth: {{item.countryBirth}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **JSON** array contains only 1 object with 3 attributes: **caseNumber**, **caseData** and **people** which is an array of objects.

You're using **ngFor** to loop through **caseData** when what you need to do is loop throught the **whole data array** and then loop through the **people** array like below:

**ComponentName.ts:**

```
dataArray =
  [{
  "caseNumber": "01/01/2020",
  "caseData": {
    "caseType": "Criminal",
    "caseCompName": "",
    "caseCompNumber": "12121212",
    "caseDate": "01/02/2019",
    "caseTime": "12:00",
    "caseStatus": "Open"
  },
  "people": [{
    "name": "Paul",
    "lastName": "Von Zeuner",
    "middleName": "Waldemar",
    "dob": "1981-09-29",
    "countryBirth": "South Africa"
  },{
    "name": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "middleName": "Steve",
    "dob": "1981-09-29",
    "countryBirth": "South Africa"
  }]
 }]
```

**ComponentName.html**

```
<div *ngFor='let item of dataArray; let i=index'>
    <div *ngFor='let person of item.people'>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            Name: {{person.name}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            Last Name: {{person.lastName}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            Middel Name: {{person.middleName}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            Country of Birth: {{person.countryBirth}}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor='let item of caseData'>
  <div *ngFor='let person of item.people'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        Name: {{person.name}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        Last Name: {{person.lastName}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        Middel Name: {{person.middleName}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        Country of Birth: {{person.countryBirth}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```